# Express-session in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I configure the express-session plugin like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    uuid = require('node-uuid');

var expiration_day = new Date('9/15/2015'),
    today = new Date(),
    session_life = Math.abs(expiration_day.getTime() - today.getTime());

var config = {
    name: 'mycookie', // session ID cookie name
    key: 'mycookie', // session ID cookie name
    secret: '$FGDFH$W#WEgfgdf',
    hash: {
        salt: '9883hjHFIDSU&U#H'
    },
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: db}),
    unset: 'keep', //never remove expired sessions
    saveUninitialized: true, //always create session, even if nothing is stored
    resave: false, //don't save session if unmodified
    ttl: session_life,
    autoRemove: 'disabled', //disable expired sessions cleaning
    genid: function (req) {
        "use strict";
        return uuid.v4();
    },
    cookie: {
        path: '/api', // cookie will be stored for requests under '/api'
        httpOnly: false,
        domain: 'example.com',
        secure: false,
        expires: expiration_day,
        maxAge: session_life
    }
};

app.sessionMW = session(config);//session middleware
```

In the Chrome and Mozilla Firefox browsers, only one session is created for the user. This session is available on all routes that use the sessionMW middleware.
So if you do a GET or POST request to /api/users/ or /api/sessions, the same session id is stored in a cookie and is sent in the cookie header for each request.

Internet Explorer does not work that way.
For each request, a new session is created. The session is stored on the server and I have confirmed that there is a new cookie in the browser for each route of the application.

I have defined the domain, the path and the expiration in the cookies.
The cookie in IE shows these values.

I do not use cookieParser, so that can't be the problem.

The problem seems to be on the client-side, anyway.
Internet Explorer is not sending the Cookie header with the request. It receives the set-cookie header in the response for each request. But the data is never re-used on subsequent requests.

Could this be a CORS issue? The cookie is not for the same domain on which I am running the application. I need a session on all routes of the API hosted on another domain.

The client-side is configured to include cookies in CORS requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true //all AJAX requests should include Cookie data
    }
});
```

I send these accept-control headers in the response to each request:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,
>
> Accept Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  http://example.com

Why is IE not setting the Cookie header in the requests?
The domain does not have underscore in its name and it does not start with a number.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-withcredentials

Answer (score 2):

For those of you using `fetch` be sure to set the credentials to `include`

```
fetch('/url/', { credentials: 'include' });
```

Otherwise the session Id will not be included with the request in IE Edge

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your server timezone and time are correct.  I just got done debugging an issue where the server's time is local but the timezone was set to UTC.  Somehow Chrome and Firefox still interpreted the expiration correctly but IE honored the UTC timezone so the cookie was already expired in its eyes.  Note that it would only immediately expire if you are in a negative timezone with respect to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Having underline in your domain name can also cause this problem.

IE and Edge don't store cookies of the domain names including underline.